# Use NLTK RegexpTokenizer to remove text between square brackets

Tags: python, regex, nltk, tokenize

I am trying to remove all the text between square from a transcript using the NLTK RegexpTokenizer:

```
file = open('speakers.txt', 'r')
read_file = file.read()

tokenizer = nltk.RegexpTokenizer(r'\[\[(?:[^\]|]*\|)?([^\]|]*)\]\]')
new_words = tokenizer.tokenize(read_file)
print(new_words)
[]
```

However, this code results in a output of only the []. What do I need to change in order to make it overwrite the [] and its contents?

Comment: Could you supply one or two examples?

Comment: Try `\[\[(?:[^]|]*\|)?([^]]*)]]|\s+` and add `gaps=True`

Comment: An example could be: **[0:00:19] spk_0: yeah. I don't want to jump in to say** 
Where the start is the timestamp. Adding your code: `tokenizer = nltk.RegexpTokenizer(r'\[\[(?:[^]|]*\|)?([^]]*)]]|\s+', gaps=True)` results in: `['[0:00:19]', 'spk_0:', 'yeah.', 'I', "don't", 'want', 'to', 'jump', 'in', 'to', 'say']`

Comment: And what would you expect?

Comment: I would expect the **[0:00:10]** part to be gone, and the rest to stay. Apologies if I did not make that clear

Comment: Oh, it seems `tokenizer = nltk.RegexpTokenizer(r'(?:\[[^][]*]|\s)+', gaps=True)` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `(?:\[[^][]*]|\s)+` regex and add the `gaps=True` argument to split with any string inside square brackets having no inner, nested brackets, and whitespace:

```py
tokenizer = nltk.RegexpTokenizer(r'(?:\[[^][]*]|\s)+', gaps=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xEf1vD/1).

**Pattern details**

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\[[^][]*]` - a `[`, then zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`, and then `]`
- `|` - or

  - `\s` - a whitespace
- `)+` - one or more repetitions of the pattern sequences in the group.